# Not able to see newly added file in git submodule

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules

I have added git submodule in my git repo. I use Jenkins to build the code. In Jenkins I do `git submodule update --init --remote`. When I modify the already existing files in the submodule it works fine. But today I added new file in git submodule repo and when I try to call that file from Jenkins or any of the script of the git submodule it shows error:
`./shared-code/check_code_status.sh: No such file or directory`
When I do `ls` in Jenkins it shows newly added file in the shared-code folder.

```
Cloning into 'shared-code'...
Submodule path 'shared-code': checked out '69c58712f110f14c368e6b1e3e65a195'
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  536 Jul  8 12:35 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 1162 Jul  8 12:35 build_and_test_app.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  476 Jul  8 12:35 check_code_status.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  923 Jul  8 12:35 badge.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 1693 Jul  8 12:35 git_tag.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  463 Jul  8 12:35 docker_image.sh
```

Can someone help in this?

Comment: `check_code_status.sh` is not marked executable (its mode is `rw-r--r--`, not `rwxr-xr-x`), so some things that try to execute it directly will fail. Some things will be more clever and will try it again as a shell script—but I suspect your Jenkins invocation is the less-clever type. Make sure the script starts with an appropriate `#!` line and is marked executable (mode 100755) when you commit it.

Comment: These permissions I see in Jenkins execute shell and other files have same permissions but those dont give this error. I tried giving 100755 permission still same error. I have wrote this file on windows notepad++ and my jenkins Instance is in Unbutu. May be some format issue due to different OS? Yes, script has `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: OK, in that case check to make sure that (a) the file is UTF-8, not UTF-16 (and has no BOM at the front); (b) it doesn't have CRLF line endings (could cause the Jenkins system to attempt to run `/bin/bash^M` rather than just `/bin/bash`).

Comment: How I can check it? from notepad++?

Comment: That, I have no idea - I don't have notepad++ (nor Windows, for that matter).